# Multiple print statements?

Tags: smart-contract, debugging

given the lack of debugging facilities in EOS contract development I add `print()` statements to my code, but I'm finding that only the first one gets printed, so:

```
print("HERE\n");
print("HERE\n");
```

prints only one "HERE".  am I doing something wrong or is that by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, I just tested this and on my computer it only show's the first message. However if you check the nodeos logs (and you have the flags `--contracts-console --verbose-http-errors`), then all of the messages are shown there.

This is a known issue that block.one decided not to fix. You can follow the lack of progress here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5647

Comment: I have both flags on.  I'm finding development on EOS most retrograde, given all the facilities we've become accustomed to in modern environments.  thanks for confirming this and glad to have people actually reading this forum

Comment: Use these flags and it should definitely be readable in the nodeos logs, not in the terminal where you do cleos though.

`--plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console --verbose-http-errors`

Comment: I had all of those turned on already.  not getting the output on the console just makes an already painful process more so.  now I have to refer to the log...

Comment: and of course, I now need to go find all the `print_debug` lines and variable number of lines that follow to capture that output.  gosh